# Releasing iOS apps built with an older SDK version

Tags: ios, release

My App Store question doesn’t seem to be answered clearly in the official guidelines document so here you go.

My app is developed for iOS8, its deployment target is 8.1. We would like to have it reviewed around next week.

Now there is the iOS9 version coming up. Will I be able to upload our binary to itunesconnect without any change? Will we have to compile with a newer SDK to pass the review process? Will I need to install a new version of Xcode do be able to upload a binary?

We would like to submit the app as is, without touching anything. (same situation as if it had been release 3 weeks ago) Is that possible? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing iOS7 code that compiles against iOS 6 Base SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303786/writing-ios7-code-that-compiles-against-ios-6-base-sdk)

Comment: There must be 500 questions on SO about this exact same issue - please search using your exact text as in the heading for some of those answers.  Note that it's faster to search than it is to wait for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will I be able to upload our binary to itunesconnect without any change?

Yes. Apple will not require that you build your app against the latest SDK. Will you have problems with folks running iOS 9? Maybe?

> Will we have to compile with a newer SDK to pass the review process?

No.

> Will I need to install a new version of Xcode do be able to upload a binary?

No.

> We would like to submit the app as is, without touching anything. (same situation as if it had been release 3 weeks ago) Is that possible?

Yes.

Also, here's a great post about the difference between the Base SDK and the Deployment Target settings: [What's the meaning of Base SDK, iOS deployment target, Target, and Project in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568572/whats-the-meaning-of-base-sdk-ios-deployment-target-target-and-project-in-xc)